# Finding sum of $\sum^{17}_{x=1}\frac{1}{1+\cot^{4}(10^\circ x)}$

Tags: trigonometry

Finding sum of $\displaystyle \sum^{17}_{x=1}\frac{1}{1+\cot^{4}(10^\circ x)}$

what i try

assume $\displaystyle A=\sum^{17}_{x=1}\frac{1}{1+\cot^{4}(10^\circ x)}=\sum^{17}_{x=1}\frac{\tan^4(10 ^\circ x)}{1+\tan^4(10^\circ x)}$

$\displaystyle A=\frac{\tan^4(10^\circ)}{1+\tan^4(10^\circ)}+\frac{\tan^4(20^\circ)}{1+\tan^4(20^\circ)}+\cdots \cdots +\frac{\tan^4(170^\circ)}{1+\tan^4(170^\circ)}$

$\displaystyle A=2\frac{\tan^4(10^\circ)}{1+\tan^4(10^\circ)}+2\frac{\tan^4(20^\circ)}{1+\tan^4(20^\circ)}+\cdots +2\frac{1+\tan^4(80^\circ)}{1+\tan^4(80^\circ)}+\frac{\tan^4(90^\circ)}{1+\tan^4(90^\circ)}$

help me to solve please .thanks

Comment: Your sum is over $k$, but $k$ does not show up in the expression.  Is this a typo?  If not, just multiply the expression by 17 and you're done.

Comment: Note that $$\frac{1}{1+\cot^{4}(90^\circ x)}\neq \frac{\tan^4(90 ^\circ x)}{1+\tan^4(90^\circ x)}$$ so you should not switch to $\tan$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**
$$\displaystyle \sum^{17}_{x=1}\frac{1}{1+\cot^{4}(10^\circ x)}=\sum^{17}_{x=1}\frac{\sin^4(10^\circ x)}{\sin^4(10^\circ x)+\cos^{4}(10^\circ x)}$$

**Hint 2**
$$\sum^{8}_{x=1}\frac{\sin^4(10^\circ x)}{\sin^4(10^\circ x)+\cos^{4}(10^\circ x)}= \sum^{8}_{x=1}\frac{\cos^4(90^\circ -10^\circ x)}{\cos^4(90^\circ-10^\circ x)+\sin^{4}(90^\circ -10^\circ x)}$$

**Hint 3**

What is 
$$\sum^{8}_{x=1}\frac{\sin^4(10^\circ x)}{\sin^4(10^\circ x)+\cos^{4}(10^\circ x)}+\sum^{8}_{x=1}\frac{\cos^4(10^\circ x)}{\sin^4(10^\circ x)+\cos^{4}(10^\circ x)}
$$

**Hint 4:** Use the same trick for $$\sum^{17}_{x=10}\frac{\sin^4(10^\circ x)}{\sin^4(10^\circ x)+\cos^{4}(10^\circ x)}$$